Custom checkstyle with STS not working.. Google Checks is by default
I have a custom checkstyle-m.xml file that I indicate in pom.xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>checkstyle-m.xml</configLocation>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>checkstyle</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>10.18.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
        

I have the file in the root path (same that pom.xml).
However, in my project Properties>Checkstyle, only appear default files: Google Checks and Sun Checks

My checkstyle-m.xml does not appear in Local Check Configurations either.
Why doesn't my file appear?
Im using STS 4.21.0
